# How can I change the fonts on Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, fonts, oracleforms

I have several forms (Oracle database and form 10) which have not been developed from the template. The current font is Time New Roman and I need to change it to Arial. Does any body have an idea apart from doing this task manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a utility from Oracle called JDAPI that you *could* consider using.  It is a Java library that alllows you to write a Java program to read and write Forms source files, making modifications such as yours programmatically.

I had to use it a couple of years ago while upgrading a lot of disparate forms to look like they belonged togther.  I can't say it was easy, unless you are already an experienced Java developer, and there were some issues where some forms would get "broken" by JDAPI and have to be done manually instead.

Comment: Thanks Tony,   It seems to work, I also found some useful information on the following web page:  http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/more-code-snippets-jdapi-change-font-for-all-items-prompts-boilerplates-frames/

Comment: It works totally fine. I changed the fonts of all forms in a second. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout my blog for a step by step example how to change the fonts.
Good Luck.

http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/more-code-snippets-jdapi-change-font-for-all-items-prompts-boilerplates-frames/

Comment: Hi, If you take a look at the comment that I have left for tony, you will see that I have already checked your blog. I just used your Java program and changed all fonts in a moment :-) thank you so much

Comment: Hi Mia, I try to change the fonts of my forms to Arial Unicode MS, but it is not possible. It just change from whatever it is to Arial. How can I change the fonts to Arial Unicode MS?